# Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.

Tags: spring, hibernate

This my utility java file:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory  = null;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateUtil.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Spring-servlet.xml:

```
    <bean id="HibernateUtil" class="com.chrysler.Utilities.HibernateUtil">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When i run this , i am getting below error:

> org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'sessionFactory' of bean class
>   [com.chrysler.Utilities.HibernateUtil]: Bean property 'sessionFactory'
>   is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter
>   type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: Now i am getting the same error for below piece of code: ContactController.java:
    public ModelAndView listContacts() {
 return new ModelAndView("contact", "contact", contactService.listContact()); 
}

I am getting below error code:
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'firstName' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'firstName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Answer (score 5):

Make the accessor methods for sessionFactory non-static